# Deep link to open a webpage where user can submit form which then takes him to app download page

Tags: branch.io

I am completely new to `branch.io`. And I am trying to incorporate this into my project. I have a use case where a person will send an invite link using branch to attend a meeting. Also this link should be unique to the invitee. Once user receives a message with link he will click on the link and it should take him to a webpage(my own)/`Deepview`(branch.io), where  he should be able to submit the form which will register him for the event. Once he finishes the registration, show him the page where there is a download app link.

So far I looked into `branch.io` documentation but i am confused what all features i should use. This is what i found so far. let me know if this is suitable for my use case or not.

For the first scenario of sending unique links i was thinking of using branch.io API as this is what their website suggests

Secondly on click of link taking user to some landing page. this is the part where i am very confused. I didn't find any article which says i can submit a form in `Deepview`. Or do i have to use my own webpage where user will submit the form and then get that information and send it to braze to create another `Deeplink` which will take user to app download page.

Please suggest me the features of `branch.io`, that I should use for my use-case

Answer (score 0):

thank you for contacting Branch. You can create a unique Branch Link with the following ways based on your situation.

- Use [Quick Links](https://docs.branch.io/dashboard/analytics/#quick-links) or [Ad Links](https://docs.branch.io/links/creating-ad-links/) from Branch Dashboard for fast link creation and easy tracking.
- Use our [App SDK](https://docs.branch.io/links/integrate/#dialog-code?ios=create-deep-link&android=create-deep-link&adobe=create-deep-link&cordova=create-deep-link&mparticleAndroid=create-deep-link&mparticleIos=create-deep-link&titanium=create-deep-link&reactNative=create-deep-link&unity=create-deep-link&xamarin=create-deep-link) to create and share links within your app.
- Use our [Web SDK](https://docs.branch.io/web/integrate/#create-deep-link) to create links which help convert your web users to app users.
- Use our [HTTP API](https://docs.branch.io/apps/api/#link-create) to programmatically create links from your server.
- Use our [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/branch-link-creator/pekdpppibljpmpbcjelehhnldnfbglgf) to generate links from your browser.

Also, you can set a different final destination (User landing page) in your Branch Link for your app based on your purpose. For example, you can make users who do not have your app in their device can land on either the App Store, [Deepview](https://branch.io/deepviews/) (is a mobile web splash page, hosted by Branch), or specific webpage via your Branch Link according to your needs.

Please feel free to contact [support@branch.io](http://support@branch.io) if you have any further questions. We are happy to help you.